# I need help declaring a file (.txt) as a user input and opening the file using open method

Tags: python-2.7, text-files

This is my code (this contains getting the filename from the user):

```
def fileInput():
#below will be modified, below is for user input
filename=input('What is the filename (include .txt):  ')
authorfile=open('home/brandon/filename.txt','r+')
##print authorfile.read();      - Deleted 8/11/15
return authorfile;
```

This is the error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "/media/brandon/Sony_32GM/Python Programs/author database_1.py", line 61, in 
    fileInput()
  File "/media/brandon/Sony_32GM/Python Programs/author database_1.py", line 37, in fileInput
    filename=input('What is the filename (include .txt):  ')
  File "", line 1, in 
NameError: name 'test1' is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 2.7, input evaluates your input as an expression, so if you just want to read a string, use raw_input:

```
def fileInput():
   #below will be modified, below is for user input
   filename=raw_input('What is the filename (include .txt):  ')
   authorfile=open('/home/brandon/' + filename,'r+')
   ##print authorfile.read();      - Deleted 8/11/15
   return authorfile;
```

Also, if you are using an absolute file path, you'll need the / before home, but if you are using a relative path, you can keep that out.

Comment: No problem. If this answered your question, can you accept my answer? Thanks.